# Display values in Vaadin table by using ColumnGenerator

Tags: java, vaadin

i am trying to display a list of dates and a string in two columns of a Table using :

```
    leaveTable.addGeneratedColumn("LeaveDate ",
            new RequestedLeaveTextShortenerColumnGenerator(1));
    leaveTable.addGeneratedColumn("LeaveType ",
            new RequestedLeaveTextShortenerColumnGenerator(2));
```

out of which leave Date will come from a List and leave type will just be a String

how can i add it using the the:

generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId){...}

please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [book of vaadin,](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html#components.table.columngenerator) there is a secion about generated table columns.

It has some code samples.

```
// Define the generated columns and their generators.
table.addGeneratedColumn("date", new DateColumnGenerator());
```

and then later on, somewhere:

```
/** Formats the value in a column containing Date objects. */
class DateColumnGenerator implements Table.ColumnGenerator {
    String format; /* Format string for the Date values. */

    /**
     * Creates date value column formatter with the given
     * format string.
     */
    public DateColumnGenerator(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    /**
     * Generates the cell containing the Double value.
     * The column is irrelevant in this use case.
     */
    public Component generateCell(Table source, Object itemId,
                                  Object columnId) {
        // Get the object stored in the cell as a property
        Property prop =
            source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(columnId);
        if (prop.getType().equals(Date.class)) {
            Label label = new Label(.......);
            return label;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```